# ERROR Error: No component factory found for TestComponent

Tags: angular, angular6, mean-stack, angular-components

I have added a new component,

```
   MlP8DocumentComponent
```

Added it in app.module.ts,

```
       declarations: [MlP8DocumentComponent, MlAmendmentDetailsComponent],
       entryComponents:[MlP8DocumentComponent, MlAmendmentDetailsComponent]
```

When I try to access it wen I click on a tab,

```
    switch (section) {
    case 'amendmentDetails': {
      factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MlAmendmentDetailsComponent);
      break;
    }
    case 'p8documents': {
      factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MlP8DocumentComponent);
      break;
    }
  }
```

It says error

```
     MlSummaryComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: No component factory found for MlP8DocumentComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

The other component in entrycomponent is working wel.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: I've answered based on the information I had, if this doesn't solve your problem kindly make a Stackblitz for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use this component in a different module, you will need to add it in the `entrycomponents` in that module and also export it in your **app.module.ts**

```
exports: [MlP8DocumentComponent]
```

Comment: Hi CodeWarior, I am using it in the same component.I just created that component and included in entryComponents.Pls help me.

Comment: Can you make a Stackblitz for it?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujnv6x?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Hey, I looked at your Stackblitz, it works as expected. Both components are loading. Where is the problem?

Comment: Thanks CodeWarrior, the problem is with my build.Resolved it.

Comment: No worries. Happy coding :)